# discord.py get message object from message link

Tags: python, discord.py

I was wondering if there was a way to get the message from the message link (https://discordapp.com/channels/guild_id/channel_id/message_id) using a Python Discord bot, and if so, how to.
I can think of a way using

```
link = 'https://discordapp.com/channels/guild_id/channel_id/message_id'.split('/')
message = await self.bot.get_guild(int(link[-3])).get_channel(int(link[-2])).fetch_message(int(link[-1]))
```

but I was wondering if there is a more direct way.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

To do this you should first get the guild, channel and message ids by doing this:

```
server_id = int(link[4])
channel_id = int(link[6])
msg_id = int(link[5])
```

Next you should use the bot to get the guild object, then use the guild object to get the text channel object and then finally use the text channel object to get the message object. Like this:

```
server = client.get_guild(server_id)
channel = server.get_channel(channel_id)
message = await channel.fetch_message(msg_id)
```

discord.py `get_guild()` reference: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_guild

discord.py `get_channel()` reference: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_channel

discord.py `fetch_message()` reference: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message

Comment: That is how I do it in my example in the question (just in one line, you can even remove the get_guild() part). I wanted to know if there was a direct way using only the link (something like a get_message_by_link(link)). Still thanks for your answer.