# Discord.py fetch message from different channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to do a bot that reacts to a message based on a command (example: `-react [link] [emote(s)]`), my initial code is:

```
@client.command()
async def react(ctx, reactmsg, *emojis):
  msg = await ctx.fetch_message(reactmsg)
  for emoji in emojis:
    await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
```

But this only works with message IDs from messages in the same channel as the command. I would like to use a message link instead + have it working with messages from other channels as well.

When I try to use an ID from a different channel or a message link instead from a message within the same channel, I just get a `NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 0): 404: Not Found` error, the bot has full access to all messages + channels needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question (reactmsg would simply have to be a message link instead of an ID)? [discord.py get message object from message link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61211559/discord-py-get-message-object-from-message-link)

Answer (score 0):

This might be really dumb, but you could try getting the guild from ctx, iterating through the channels and searching each one for the reactmsg ID.

It's not pretty, but it worked:

```
import discord.errors
@bot.command()
async def react(ctx, reactmsg, *emojis):
    try:
        msg = await ctx.fetch_message(reactmsg)
        for emoji in emojis:
            await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
    except discord.errors.NotFound:
        print('not in this channel, need to do it the hard way')
        for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
            print('searching in channel ' + channel.name)
            try:
                msg = await channel.fetch_message(reactmsg)
                for emoji in emojis:
                    await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
            except discord.errors.NotFound:
                print('didn\'t find it in    ' + channel.name)
            except AttributeError:
                print('not a text channel to do a search in')
```

I think ctx.fetch_message is the exact same as channel.fetch_message, and there's no such thing as guild.fetch_message (unless I'm blind, or looking in the wrong place), which is why it didn't work originally.

Comment: My friend suggested this as well after thinking for a while, but the solution from @TheFungusAmongUs works better