# Getting the view() object from message

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

so my problem is that i have a view from a message right, and im saving the message id in a database for a later time

when that time comes around i want to make the view buttons disabled, but I need the view object again for this.

basically I need the view object from my message object

thank you in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on Views isn't up on https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/, so I've been using pycord documentation, because they seem basically the same for a lot of this. https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=view#discord.ui.View.from_message is what you want to be using.

The problem is that if you're just saving message IDs, you're going to search around to find the channel that the message was in, so that you can get the message object.  The easiest way to do that is just use a message link instead of a message ID, because then you know the guild, channel, and message ID. If you're stuck with only message IDs, you could search like this: [Discord.py fetch message from different channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71440488/discord-py-fetch-message-from-different-channel/71442833#71442833)

once you find the right channel, you just need to get the message, and get the view out of it with View.from_message.

```
message = channel.fetch_message(messageID)
view = discord.ui.view.from_message(message)
```

I'm not sure if pycord's from_message is different from discord.py's but here's the discord.ui.view.py does have from_message.

```
    def from_message(cls, message: Message, /, *, timeout: Optional[float] = 180.0) -> View:
        """Converts a message's components into a :class:`View`.

        The :attr:`.Message.components` of a message are read-only
        and separate types from those in the ``discord.ui`` namespace.
        In order to modify and edit message components they must be
        converted into a :class:`View` first.

        Parameters
        -----------
        message: :class:`discord.Message`
            The message with components to convert into a view.
        timeout: Optional[:class:`float`]
            The timeout of the converted view.

        Returns
        --------
        :class:`View`
            The converted view. This always returns a :class:`View` and not
            one of its subclasses.
        """
        view = View(timeout=timeout)
        for component in _walk_all_components(message.components):
            view.add_item(_component_to_item(component))
        return view
```

https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ui/view.py

Answer (score 0):

```
discord.ui.View.from_message()
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=discord%20ui%20view%20from_message#discord.ui.View.from_message